# Finding unknown in a polynomial given unknown factor.

Tags: polynomials

The polynomial $2x^4 - ax^3 + 19x^2 - 20x + 12$ has the factor in the form $(x-k)^2$, where $k$ is positive real integer. Find the value of $k$ and $a$ and show that the polynomial is non-negative for all real values of $x$.

I can't figure out any way to solve this with an unknown factor.
Is there any way to do this question?
Or the question is missing something?

The answer for this question is $k=2, a=10$.

Comment: I don't see a way around calculating the discriminant of your polynomial. If there is a double root, then the discriminant must vanish. But, the discriminant is a quartic in $a$. It has two real zeros (one of them is, indeed, $a=10$), and two complex zeros.

Comment: Oh (looking at Ross' post), you were given that the double root is an integer. That does help.

Comment: Is $a$ assumed to be an integer?

Comment: The question did not said so. But it should be an integer. Because a might be something that will affect the next question says the polynomial is non negative for all values of x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ *EDIT* ]  *The original answer is in the P.S. at the bottom of this post. Immediately following is a different and complete answer*.

For $P(x) = 2x^4 - ax^3 + 19x^2 - 20x + 12$ to have a double root, it must have that root in common with its derivative $P'(x) = 8 x^3 -3 a x^2 +38 x - 20$. Eliminating $a$ between the two equations $P(x)=P'(x)=0$ gives:

$$
Q(x) = 2 x^4 - 19 x^2 + 40 x - 36 = 0
$$

Therefore any double root of $P$ must be a root of $Q$. It is easily verified that any integer root of $Q$:

- must be a divisor of $36$;
- must be even since the polynomial has exactly one odd coefficient;
- if a multiple of $3$ it must be a multiple of $9$ otherwise the equality fails $\bmod 9$.

Given that the double root is assumed to be a *positive* integer, the above leaves $x=2,4,18,36 \;$ $(\dagger)\;$ as the only eligible roots. By direct verification, $2$ is the only one which is in fact a root of $Q(x)$.

Substituting $x=2$ back in $P(x)=0$ gives $a=10$. Given how the derivation worked, $x=2$ is known at this point to be a double root of $P$ for $a=10$ so no further verification is necessary.

$\dagger\;$ *Note*: if $a$ is assumed to be an integer, then the common root would have to be a divisor of $\gcd(12, 20, 36) = 4$ which would limit the eligible values to just $2,4$.

---

[ *EDIT* ]   P.S. *Below is the original answer*.

Partial but quick solution: let $2x^4 - ax^3 + 19x^2 - 20x + 12 = (2 x^2 + b x + c)(x^2 - 2k x + k^2)$.

*Assume* that $c \in \mathbb{Z}\;$ ("*assume*" because $c$ is not otherwise required to be an integer), then it follows that $k^2 \mid 12$ with integer solutions $k = \pm 1, \pm 2$. The polynomial has no negative roots by the rule of signs, which leaves $k=1,2$ as candidates.

- $k=1$ implies $2 - a + 19 - 20 + 12 = 0$ so $a=13$. But the derivative $8 x^3 - 39 x^2 + 38 x - 20$ does not vanish at $x=1$ so $1$ is not a double root.
- following the same steps, $k=2$ gives $a=10$ which can be verified to satisfy all conditions.

Note that the above finds *one* solution quickly, but does not prove that it's the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

The rational root theorem restricts the integral values of $k$ to be factors of $12$, so you only have $12$ choices (positive and negative).  If nothing else, you can do polynomial long division to try each of them.  The $a$ will carry through the division.  For example, if we try $k=-1$ we get $2x^4 - ax^3 + 19x^2 - 20x + 12=(x+1)^2[2x^2+(4-a)x+25-2a]+(5a-74)x+(2a-13)$
For $(x+1)^2$ to be a factor we would have to be able to find a value of $a$ that made both the remainder terms zero, but there is not one.  This means $k=-1$ does not solve our problem.  There may be a cleverer way to find the proper value of $k$, but I haven't seen it.  Once you find $k$ and $a$ you have a known quartic.  You can then find the local minima and show they are all positive.

Comment: You can halve the search space by noting that $k \gt 0$ by the rule of signs.

Comment: Can we substitute the k value into the equation and find the a? For eg k=1 or 2 or 3 or any factors of 12.

Comment: @MoyJianJun:  yes, you could do long division as I did with $(x-k)^2$.  At the end you will have two remainder terms that depend on $a$ and $k$.  You can then set them both to zero and solve the simultaneous equations.  That should find the values for $a$ and $k$.  The long division would be messier, but it would save trying all the $k$ values.  A good approach.

Comment: On a second read, I realized that the problem does not specify that $a$ must be an integer, in which case $k$ wouldn't necessarily have to be a factor of $12$. $a$ needs to be rational, of course, but it could conceivably be a fraction. I posted a comment asking the OP to clarify that part (though the result seems to follow without that assumption, too).